# Facebook erroneously complains about meta tags in body

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

I'm trying to implement a like button, but having some problems with the meta tags. The Facebook debugger is complaining that I have "Meta Tags In Body",http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Filovemymk.se, even though I don't. And refuses to recognize any of the meta information.

I am also checking the page at Open Graph Checker, http://ogp.spypixel.com/Pogo/checker/index.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Filovemymk.se, and it gives me no errors at all and all information is fetched correctly.

What do I need to change for Facebook to correctly fetch my meta data?

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Filovemymk.se%2F) is what the debugger is seeing at your url. I can see a `<p>` tag within which you have kept meta tags. i think this `<p>` tag is what making debugger to see it as within `<body>`. you should try removing `<p>` tags from before meta tags. and keep the meta tags explicitly within `<head>` tags.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why on earth does it see a paragraph there? Because there is none in the source code!

Comment: I removed the rdf namespaces. Dunno why Facebook didn't parse it correctly.